# Match timestamp pairs by maximal time interval

Tags: c++, sorting, data-structures, timestamp

I'm reading two input files. In both I'm getting timestamps in the form of seconds since 1970. Let's mark them `A1,A2,...` and `B1,B2,...`

I need to return all of the timestamp pairs, where `Ai` happened before `Bj` and their interval is no more than `X` seconds from each other.

The timestamps are not arriving in a chronological order, but are all from the same calendarical day.

What would be the most efficient way to calculate these pairs? What data structure should I use to store the input streams?

Comment: Why not sort the files first?  Then the code is easier.  If not, read each one into a std::set which will order them.  Then process the ordered values.

Comment: I am thinking that firstly u need to sort the files and secondly apply one pass merge algorithm with your x(time stamp)